# ruby rspec mocks test function receiving a hash

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd, rspec3

I am toying with the mailgun API, all functionalities seem to work now and I want to test them using rspec mocks.

I made some json fixtures under the rspec/fixtures folder, each has a json representing the expected result when I call a particular function. I also made a small helper:

```
module TestHelpers
  def self.get_json(filename:)
    JSON.parse File.read(filename)
  end
end
```

What I want to test is this function:

```
def self.get_messages_for(email:)
    sent_emails = []
    delivered_events = get_events_for(email: email)

    # :Accept => "message/rfc2822" will help us to get the raw MIME
    delivered_events.each do |event|
      response = RestClient::Request.execute method: :get ,
                                              url: event["storage"]["url"],
                                              user: "api", password:"#{configuration.api_key}",
                                              Accept: "message/rfc2822"
      sent_emails.push(JSON.parse(response))
    end
    sent_emails
  end
```

Which uses this helper to fetch events:

```
def self.get_events_for(email:, event_type: "delivered")
    delivered_to_target = []
    response = RestClient.get "https://api:#{configuration.api_key}"\
    "@api.mailgun.net/v3/#{configuration.api_domain}/events",
    :params => {
      :"event" => event_type
    }

    all_delivered = JSON.parse(response)["items"]

    all_delivered.each do |delivered|
      if (delivered.has_key?("recipients") and delivered["recipients"].include?(email)) or
        (delivered.has_key?("recipient") and delivered["recipient"].include?(email))
        delivered_to_target.push(delivered)
      end
    end
    delivered_to_target
  end
```

And here in my spec I have:

```
it 'can get the list of previously sent emails to an email address' do

    allow(StudySoup).to receive(:get_events_for).with({email: email}) {
      Array(TestHelpers::get_json(filename: 'spec/fixtures/events.json'))
    }

    allow(RestClient::Request).to receive(:execute).with(any_args){
      TestHelpers::get_json(filename: 'spec/fixtures/messages.json')
    }

    expect(StudySoup.get_messages_for(email: email)["subject"]).not_to be nil
  end
```

However, when I tried to run rspec, it always has the following fail trace:

```
1) StudySoup can get the list of previously sent emails to an email address
     Failure/Error: url: event["storage"]["url"],

     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of String into Integer
     # ./lib/StudySoup.rb:51:in `[]'
     # ./lib/StudySoup.rb:51:in `block in get_messages_for'
     # ./lib/StudySoup.rb:49:in `each'
     # ./lib/StudySoup.rb:49:in `get_messages_for'
     # ./spec/StudySoup_spec.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I thought I stubbed out the `RestClient::Request.execute` method so it should work but it didn't. Any ideas on how I can correctly test this function? I tried to put many params matcher like anything(), hash_including(:key => value)... but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed stubbed out the `execute` method. This means that rspec fiddles with that class so that attempts to call `execute` call rspec provided code instead of the original inplementation. In particular, all the arguments to that call are evaluated as normal.

Changing the argument matchers as you have tried changes whether rspec decides the method call matches one of the configured stubs, but can't avoid the fact that evaluating `event["storage"]["url"]` is raising an exception.

When you stubbed `get_events_for` you returned an array of arrays instead of an array of hashes: `Array` calls `to_ary` or `to_a` on its arguments which is turning your hash into an array of key value pairs, rather than wrapping the hash in an array as I think you thought it did.

Comment: In the events.json file I have only one json Hash, so the result of my get_json is a Hash (I've tested this in a separate rb script). Normally in production get_events_for will return an Array of Hashes so I think I should cast get_json to Array (I've also tried removing the cast but it also didn't work)

Comment: is there any way I can stub out event["storage"]["url"]? something like event = double
allow(event).to receive(:[])...

Comment: Ah, so the issue is that Array(foo) doesn't do what you think - it's not the same as [foo]

Comment: so how do I construct an Array containing only one Hash? I did a quick search and casting into Array is the only thing I found

Comment: Like i said `[foo]`

Comment: thank you very much sir, have a good day, now I'm gonna read up on the difference between Hash and []. It works. :)